# Entity Framework - How to check if table exists?

Tags: c#, sql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using the Entity Framework with Code First approach. The base class DbContext has functions to create and delete the database as well as to check for its existence.

I want to check if a special table (entity) is existing or not. Is it possible with an framework implementation or do I need to write custom methods? If I need to write my own implementation, what would be the most generic approach to do that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you need to check existence of the table you must call custom SQL code:

```
bool exists = context.Database
                     .SqlQuery<int?>(@"
                         SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables AS T
                         INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id
                         WHERE S.Name = 'SchemaName' AND T.Name = 'TableName'")
                     .SingleOrDefault() != null;
```

Table name is defined by default as the name of `DbSet` exposed on your derived context but the default name can be overriden either by fluent API's `ToTable` method or `Table` data annotation.

Doing this in the generic way is not something supposed in code first approach. That will require browsing metadata and manually explore to which table is the entity mapped - this can be pretty complex because entity can be mapped to multiple tables. Code first doesn't offer access to metadata. You must convert `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` and browse `MetadataWorkspace`.

Edit:

To convert `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` use this:

```
ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
```

Comment: How can I convert DbContext to ObjectContext? I've seend diffrent approaches to check for the existence of a table. Is there any difference between your solutin an a) SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable')) or b)
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableName]') AND type in (N'U')? Could you explain advantages/disadvantages? I would prefer to use a most standard conform way.

Comment: Generally all these SQL selects query the same information - that is just different way to get the same result.

Comment: What does type in (N'U') mean? Your version does ignore the table schema, right?

Comment: I modified query to work with schema as well. Here you have list of types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx `U` means user defined table.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (maybe due to MS changing SQL server?).  All my `S.Name` are "dbo", so there are no results.

Answer (score 6):

I can't add comment to previous post. I'm using SQL Compact and I don't know schema of the table. I'm using this code to check for table It's pretty the same that in previous post but It works for any table.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if data table is exist in application
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Class of data table to check</typeparam>
    /// <param name="db">DB Object</param>
    public static bool CheckTableExists<T>(this ModelLocker db) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            db.Set<T>().Count();
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: catching any random exception doesn't necessarily mean the table doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, using Any may improve the query in case it exists

Answer (score 4):

An alternative method; it's not as efficient as Ladislav's, but it's not tied to SQL Server (edited to add Where clause to address performance issue):

```
bool CheckTableExists()
{
    try
    {
        context.YourTable.Where(s => s.<yourKeyField> = <impossible value>).Count();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont use exceptions for flow control, its an anti pattern

Comment: Agree Exceptions are used only for 'exceptions' not to normal operations.

Comment: It might be that the exception is only ever used once for a check. I can't see any harm if usage is one-time.

Answer (score 3):

In EF Core, I have added the TableExists method as a extension method for the DbContext class. Here is my solution using Dapper.

```
using System.Linq;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public static class DbContextsExtensions
{
    public static bool TableExists(this DbContext dbContext, string tableName)
    {
        var sqlQ = $"SELECT COUNT(*) as Count FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{tableName}'";

        var conn = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                // Query - method extension provided by Dapper library
                var count = conn.Query<int>(sqlQ).FirstOrDefault();

                return (count > 0);                    
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is an usage example:

```
if(context != null && context.TableExists("AppSettings"))
{
   // do something;
}
```

Hope this help other people.

Comment: But how can you access DBContext in Migration ?

Answer (score 2):

Assumption: SQL Server

Catching any old exception when querying the `DbSet` does not mean the table does not exist.

Querying a `DbSet` where the table does not exist will throw an `EntityCommandExecutionException` with an inner exception of type `SqlException`.  That inner exception has an `ErrorNumber` property.

Error number 208 reads ([source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645611)):

> Invalid object name '%.*ls'.

Comment: The property is actually named Number.

Answer (score 2):

I think following code is a little bit more understandable.

```
using(YourDbEntities db = new YourDbEntities()) 
{
  bool IsExists = db.Database
   .SqlQuery <int?> (@"
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + yourTableName + "'
    ")
    .FirstOrDefault() > 0;

    return IsExists;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension method for doing this in EF Core (without Dapper):

```
public static async Task<bool> TableExists(this DbContext context, string tableName)
{
    var connection = (SqlConnection)context.Database.GetDbConnection();
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
    }

    await using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.tables WHERE name = '{tableName}'";
    var result = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
    var count = (int)result;
    return count > 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be `count > 0`?

Answer (score -2):

this code create all tables automatic if dose not exist

```csharp
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            var x = modelBuilder.RegisterEntityType;
        }
```

Comment: That's not the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).