# Check if Index exists on table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to check if an index exists in a specific table using EF Core. I tried the solution below:

[Entity Framework - How to check if table exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100969/entity-framework-how-to-check-if-table-exists)

```
return context.Database.SqlQuery<int?>($"SELECT 1 as Value FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = '{indexName}' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('{schema}.{table}') AND is_unique_constraint = 0").SingleOrDefault() != null;
```

which evaluates into:

```
SELECT 1 as Value FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'UK_value_type' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('utl.value_type') AND is_unique_constraint = 0
```

But this query always returns `false`. If I run the same query directly (in SSMS), the result is there, since the index 100% exists:

```
2050106344  UK_value_type   3   2   NONCLUSTERED    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   NULL    NULL    0   0
```

Comment: Might be, but I can query the `sys.tables` table just fine, with the same user. Also, I run the SSMS query with the exact same user also.

Comment: Remove the quotes and pass schema.table as one parameter.

Comment: @GertArnold it's already passed as one parameter though. without quotes, it just throws an error, since string is expected

Comment: `SqlQuery` turns interpolated strings into parameters, the parameters are evaluated by the db engine which is type-aware. Just try it and monitor the query. Otherwise use `SqlQueryRaw`.

Comment: oh wow, you are right, i will post a comment with your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, interpolated strings are turned into typed parameters, so if you run SQL Profiler, I expect what you'll see actually being run is:

```
WHERE name = '@p0' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('@p1.@p2') AND is_unique_constraint = 0
```

A simple test case for this is:

```
var stringIn = "test";

var query1 = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>($"SELECT '{stringIn}' AS Value").SingleOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine($"Query 1: {query1}");

var query2 = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>($"SELECT {stringIn} AS Value").SingleOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine($"Query 2: {query2}");

var query3 = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>($"SELECT Value FROM (VALUES ('test')) AS x (Value) WHERE Value = '{stringIn}'").SingleOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine($"Query 2: {query3 ?? "Null"}");

var query4 = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>($"SELECT Value FROM (VALUES ('test')) AS x (Value)  WHERE Value = {stringIn}").SingleOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine($"Query 4: {query4 ?? "Null"}");
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Query 1: @p0   //Literal string for parameter name
Query 2: test  //Actual parameter value
Query 2: Null  // No results because "Test" != "@p0"
Query 4: test  //Result returned because "Test" = "Test"
```

Finally, getting `SingleOrDefault()` then checking for null could be simplified a bit by using `Any()`.

So all in all this should work for you:

```
return context.Database.SqlQuery<int?>($"SELECT 1 as Value FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = {indexName} AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(CONCAT(QUOTENAME({schema}), '.', QUOTENAME({table}))) AND is_unique_constraint = 0").Any();
```

**ADDENDUM**

To address the comments, the likely reason you get an error without quotes is because it was creating malformed SQL:

```
object_id = OBJECT_ID(@p1.@p2)
```

This is why in the above I've used `CONCAT()` (along with `QUOTENAME()`) to build the object name, ending up with something like:

```
object_id = OBJECT_ID(CONCAT(QUOTENAME(@p1), '.', QUOTENAME(@p2)))
```